# Debugging the C++ file called by an executable file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, exe

I have an exe file which will execute the cpp files and capture the results. I want to debug the cpp file which is being called by the exe file in the visual studio. 
Currently 
I am loading the exe file as a project in the Visual studio, i open the c++ code which is called by exe file as well and keep breakpoints at relevant places. when I run the exe file it does not stop at the breakpoint but continues execution and stops. 
Is any settings to be made in the visual studio to gain control over the cpp code while debugging.

Comment: How do you start the program? But just *running* it or by *debugging* it?

Comment: @Santosh, Please really debug your app using F5(Start debugging) after you add a breakpoint to the code line in your cpp file, not run your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", please also make sure that your app was in debug mode(not release mode), and the code was not optimized. If the breakpoint was hit, it means that the code in this cpp file was really called by your exe file.

Comment: cpp files are not executed, they are compiled.

Comment: Used procedure described in the following link to open the exe in visual studio https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bxe8ytt.aspx.
From the solution explorer right clicked on the exe file and selected debug. 
The file ran as expected but didnt not stop at the breakpoint

Comment: @Santosh, my understanding it was different from yours, it was used to debug the .exe outside the VS, you really want to debug a library which was called by the .exe, maybe you could refer to this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@santosh I think you are loading VC++ Project file(Not Exe file)

1. you have t build your project (compilation of the project).
2. Put a breakpoint in menu bar debugging->start debugging or Press F5.
3. Even though your debugger not hitting the breakpoint check your "**symbols**" in VisualStudio in menu bar **Tools -> Options -> Debugging-> Symbols** tick the **Microsoft symbol servers** press ok.
4. Again build your project and debug.